# How do i know when the second factor when factoring a cubic expression is also factorizable?

Tags: factoring, partial-fractions

Let's say I have to factor $x^3 + 1$.

Now I know that the first factor will be $(x+1)$ because when you input -1 into the function you get $0$. And the rest is all about the factor-remainder theorem right.

Now i will obtain another factor when i divide $x^3 +1$ by $(x+1)$, which is
$x^2 - x + 1$.

How do I know if the third factor is then factorizable? I'm asking because if I had to perform partial fraction decomposition, I would have to know.

I cannot test the factorizability of it by finding the discriminant, because the discriminant also tells me that the expression is factorizable when the solutions are not whole numbers.

And when spreading an expression into partial fractions , i believe that you are only asked to do that when the solutions are whole numbers.

So is there another way i can know?

Comment: The discriminant tells you everything you need to know. If it's not a perfect square, the solutions aren't rationals.

Comment: @GerryMyerson let's say I have the discriminant to be 64. And x to be 5+8 / 3. this then is 11/3, which is not a whole number.

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes, it's rational, but for partial fraction decomposition , am i not supposed to give factors with whole numbers only in them?

Comment: which third factor ? You factorized $x^3+1=(x+1)(x^2-x+1)$ and just have to check whether $x^2-x+1$ is factorizable (terminology "reducible").

Comment: @Peter well, sure in this case there is no third factor(at least not in the real world), but in other cases, the quadratic factor might also be ''reducible'' as you say.

Comment: @sweetlovely: If the discriminant is greater than or equal to $0$, then the quadratic can be factorised. However, as you mention, this factorisation might be 'nice' as the numbers in the factors might be rationals. If the discriminant is less than $0$, then the quadratic *cannot* be factored. Here, $b^2-4ac=1-4(1)(1)=-3<0$, and therefore $x^2-x+1$ does not have any real roots. Hence, it cannot be factorised (over the real numbers).

Comment: @Joe , yeah i know. i just wished there was another way to know whether whole numbers or fractions would make up the factors...

Comment: @sweetlovely: If you have a quadratic $ax^2+bx+c$, then it can be factorised 'nicely' if you can find integers $p$ and $q$ such that $p\cdot q=a\cdot c$ and $p+q=b$.

Comment: @Joe lol i don't know how i forgot about this. Of course, that's the way to do it!

Comment: For partial fractions, you can use whole numbers, or integers, or rationals, or any reals whatsoever. If $ax^2+bx+c$ factors as $(rx+s)(tx+u)$, and $P(x)$ is linear,  then you can express $P(x)/(ax^2+bx+c)$ as $${A\over rx+s}+{B\over tx+u}$$ for some real numbers $A,B$, and then you can integrate if that's called for.

Comment: My immediately preceding comment holds provided $b^2-4ac\ne0$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson by Px im assuming you meean Fx

Comment: so ,we can really choose what we're using @GerryMyerson. is that what you mean? in other words i can choose to use a linear with one quadratic that doesnt factorize to give whole numbers as solutions?

Comment: I don't mean Px or Fx, I mean $P(x)$. But what's the difference between writing $P(x)$ and writing $F(x)$? Also, I don't know what you mean by "whole numbers as solutions". Solutions of what? You're talking about partial fraction decomposition, let's say of $(2x^2+3)/(x^3-2x-1)$. Well, you can write it as $${A\over x+1}+{Bx+C\over x^2-x-1}$$ and then work out $A,B,C$ (and they might or might not be integers, but who cares?). Or, you can write it as $${A\over x+1}+{B\over x-r}+{C\over x-s}$$ where $r,s$ are the roots of $x^2-x-1$ and (continued)

Comment: (continued) work out $A,B,C$ (and they might not even be rationals, but who cares). Which of these two ways of doing partial fractions you use depends on why you want a partial fraction decomposition in the first place. Maybe one way is more convenient for one kind of application, and the other way is more convenient for some other kind of application. One more thing: I think you're using "whole number" when you mean "integer". $-17$ (for example) isn't a whole number, but it is an integer.

Comment: i meant where s and r are not whole numbers.

Comment: lets say s and r are fractions. do i then leave my answer as A/ linear + Bx+C/ quadratic?

Comment: and why. let's chat about it.

Comment: If you want to be sure I see a comment that's meant for me, you have to put @Gerry in it. Now, I wrote that whether you leave your answer with the unfactored quadratic depends on what you intend to do with your answer. I don't know what you intend to do with your answer, so I can't tell you whether to leave your answer with the unfactored quadratic.

Comment: i just want to spread my answer into partial fractions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the discriminant is less than $0$, then the quadratic cannot be factorised. If it is greater than or equal to $0$, then the quadratic can be factorised, although this factorisation might be messy. The quadratic $ax^2+bx+c$ can be factorised over the integers if you can find two numbers $p$ and $q$ such that $p\cdot q = a \cdot c$ and $p+q=b$. Here is an example:
\begin{align}
3x^2+10x+8 &= 3x^2+6x+4x+8 \\[5pt]
&= 3x(x+2)+4(x+2) \\[5pt]
&= (3x+4)(x+2) \, .
\end{align}
This is sometimes called the "[AC method](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/x2f8bb11595b61c86:quadratics-multiplying-factoring/x2f8bb11595b61c86:factor-quadratics-grouping/a/factoring-quadratics-leading-coefficient-not-1)".

Answer (score 0):

It fully depends upon the districiminant. If the discriminant $b^2-4ac>0$ then the polynomial can be factorised and it will give rational or irrational roots. However if the discriminant $< 0$ then the equation cannot be factorised.

Learn  more about discriminant - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant

Also if this might be of any help [Vieta formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20Vieta%27s%20formulas%20are,are%20used%20specifically%20in%20algebra.) can also help. It states that if in polynomial $ax^2+bx+c=0$ and roots are $\alpha, \beta$ then $ \alpha+\beta=\frac{-b}{a} , \alpha\beta=\frac{c}{a}$

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: Your claim is false. It is entirely possible for a quadratic polynomial to be factorizable over R, but without rational roots.

Comment: Thanks @SaucyO'Path now edited the answer